# Dynamic rendering of N shiny tabs

Tags: user-interface, shiny, dynamic, tabs

I try to develop an R shiny app that renders n tabs. n should be hard coded in the server function and not be modified by the user. From these n rendered tabs, initially only the first tab should be displayed and all the others should be hidden. Each tab should includes a button that should switch to the next tab until n is reached. Very greatful for any hints

Here is the last test which did not run:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("tabs")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  num_tabs <- 5  # Define the number of tabs
  
  output$tabs <- renderUI({
    tabs <- lapply(1:num_tabs, function(i) {
      tabPanel(
        paste("Tab", i),
        actionButton(inputId = paste0("switch_tab_", i), label = "Switch Tab")
      )
    })
    
    tabsetPanel(
      id = "tabs_content",
      do.call(tabPanel, c(tabs, id = paste0("tab_", 1:num_tabs)))
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    for (i in 2:num_tabs) {
      runjs(paste("$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(", i, ")').hide();"))
      runjs(paste("$('.tab-content .tab-pane:nth-child(", i, ")').hide();"))
    }
  })
  # 
  observeEvent({
    lapply(1:num_tabs, function(i) {
      input[[paste0("switch_tab_", i)]]
    })
  }, {
    current_tab <- isolate({
      tab_selected <- i
      as.numeric(tab_selected)
    })

    if (!is.na(current_tab) && current_tab < num_tabs) {
      next_tab <- current_tab + 1
      runjs(paste("$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(", next_tab, ")').show();"))
      runjs(paste("$('.tab-content .tab-pane:nth-child(", next_tab, ")').show();"))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You need to specify the event expression you are observing in `observeEvent({...})`.

Comment: I agree that was a misstake since there is no event I changed it to observe({...)} but this doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues.  First, you need to have `useShinyjs()` in the  `ui`. Next, all five tabs were not even created, as `tabsetPanel` does not accept `lists` (named tabs in your case).  Next, use `updateTabsetPanel` to switch tabs; you need `session` in the server function for that.  I also added a previous tab, in case you wish to go back to previous tab.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("tabs")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  num_tabs <- 5  # Define the number of tabs

  ### create 5 tabs
  output$tabs <- renderUI({
    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id="tabs_content",
                           lapply(1:num_tabs, function(i) {
                             tabPanel(title = paste("Tab", i), value = paste0("tab_", i),
                                      if (i>1) actionButton(inputId = paste0("prev_tab_", i), label = paste("Previous Tab")),
                                      if (i<5) actionButton(inputId = paste0("switch_tab_", i), label = paste("Next Tab"))  
                             )
                           })
    ))
  })

  ###  Initially, hide tabs 2 thru 5
  observeEvent(input$tabs_content, {
    for (i in 2:num_tabs) {
      runjs(paste("$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(", i, ")').hide();"))
      #runjs(paste("$('.tab-content .tab-pane:nth-child(", i, ")').hide();"))
    }
  }, once = TRUE)

  ### upon clicking on the actionButton, open the next tab
  lapply(1:(num_tabs-1), function(i) {
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("switch_tab_", i)]], {
      next_tab <- i+1
      runjs(paste("$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(", next_tab, ")').show();"))
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs_content", selected=paste0("tab_",next_tab) )
      runjs(paste("$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(", i, ")').hide();"))
      #runjs(paste("$('.tab-content .tab-pane:nth-child(", next_tab, ")').show();"))
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  })

  lapply(2:num_tabs, function(i) {
    observeEvent(input[[paste0("prev_tab_", i)]], {
      prev_tab <- i-1
      runjs(paste("$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(", prev_tab, ")').show();"))
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs_content", selected=paste0("tab_",prev_tab) )
      runjs(paste("$('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(", i, ")').hide();"))
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This works almost perfect. The only thing is that after clicking the btn the "old" tab should be hided. At the moment the behaviour is that the old tabs stay visible.

Comment: Try the updated code. I added another action button for previous tab, if a user wishes to go back to previous tab.

Comment: Perfect, works very nice, thanks a lot!